# Network communication

Tags: networking

What component of operating system is responsible for network communication?
I also want to know what input/output it takes/receive during this communication. It would be a great help if I can have a architecture of that component.

Comment: Please could you make it clearer what you are asking? Do you mean which program? if so, it is installed by defaut on ubuntu, and called Newtork Manager.

Comment: Really, the component responsible for network communication is the Linux kernel... What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point if you to understand networking under Linux is [Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control Howto](http://www.lartc.org/howto).

You'll get here and extensive description of the networking stack of linux, and the userland tools that will give you full control on it.

Also, in [prior knowledge](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.intro.prior.html) section, you have links to more general documentations that might be helpful to fully understand the subject.

Answer (score 0):

"what component of Operating system is responsible for network communication?"

I assume you mean what program, not component. In Ubuntu it is called Network Manager, and can be run from the terminal or run dialouge with `network-manager`. It should auto start, and is visible in the status bar at the top. If you have a WiFi connection, it looks like a radio wave. Ethernet looks like 2 arrows, going in opposite directions.

"what input/output it takes/receive during this communication"

That would be better asked on stack overflow, or you could read [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_protocol).

"It would be a great help if I can have a architecture of that component"

What is "a architecture of that component"? The application can be found in both 64 bit and 32 bit Ubuntu installations. You could install it from the terminal, `sudo apt-get install network-manager`, and that would automatically select the correct archetechture for your installation, however it isn't nessecary, as already stated above, it comes installed with ubuntu.

You might mean the source code, in which case is avaliable from Ubuntu, as it is all open source.